# UpdateProgress not working for button which is in inside of trigger property

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
      <table width="100%"><tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="3">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnShowReport" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonClassLong" SkinID="LargeButton"
                                    Text="Show Report" OnClick="btnShowReport_Click"   TabIndex="15" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonClass" Text="Clear" OnClick="btn_Click"
                                    TabIndex="16" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonClass" OnClick="btnClose_Click"
                                    Text="Close" CausesValidation="False" TabIndex="17" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkPrint" Text="Print View" runat="server" TabIndex="14" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnShowReport" />
</Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel><asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/RIBO/Images/Progress.gif" AlternateText="Processing"
                    runat="server" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This is my coding , My issue is when i click the clear button the update progress working well, when i click btnShowReport it wont work.

how to show the update progress for button click event which is in inside the trigger property.

Comment: What for you need synchronous postback on `btnShowReport` click?

Comment: I want , if i click btnShowReport the UpdateProgress will show...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6451745/360171

Answer (score 5):

Problem is `AssociatedUpdatePanelID` . You havn't set Associateid of your 'UpdateProgress`

set it on `UpdateProgress`

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server"  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Upnl1">
```

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx)

> The UpdateProgress control renders a element that is displayed or hidden 
>       depending on   whether an associated UpdatePanel control has caused an 
>       asynchronous postback. For initial page rendering and for synchronous 
>        postbacks, the UpdateProgress control is not displayed.

**EDIT**:

Reason is `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnShowReport" />`

Which will cause a full page postback. You should change your `Trigger` to

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnShowReport" />
```

and it will do the job for you...If you could have read the quoted statement you would have able to solve it by yourself too...

Comment: I set the property AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Upnl1" but it wont work(update progress not showing)....

Comment: If I use `async` anything that is selected in the front-end (fileupload control filename) is not sent to the code-behind...

Comment: @Si8 please check this link, Let me know if this does not helps https://pumexintellecto.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/asp-net-fileupload-partial-postback/

Comment: I just did some research and file upload requires full postback unfortunately. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

[This is working for me, I hope this will helpful for some](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/06/updateprogress-not-working-with-postbacktrigger-in-aspnet-ajax-updatepanel.html)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Show Loading Image while uploading images using updatepanel</title>
<style type="text/css">
.overlay
{
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: Black;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity: 0.6;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showProgress() {
var updateProgress = $get("<%= UpdateProgress.ClientID %>");
updateProgress.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div style="align:center; margin-left:350px; margin-top:200px">
<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfiles1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" onclick="btnUpload_Click" OnClientClick="showProgress()" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"/>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatepanel1">
<ProgressTemplate>
<div class="overlay">
<div style=" z-index: 1000; margin-left: 350px;margin-top:200px;opacity: 1;-moz-opacity: 1;">
<img alt="" src="loading.gif" />
</div>
</div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.